# GeoServer 2.20.4 winsetup download not available

Tags: geoserver, installation, windows

despite the fact that the page http://geoserver.org/release/2.20.4/ provides a link to a windows installer set (https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.20.4/GeoServer-2.20.4-winsetup.exe), it seems to be missing.

Will it become available any time soon?

Comment: Its the only version that suits you?

Comment: Just copy the War file into the previous install

Answer (score 3):

Sorry our build server had file permission issues uploading that (from azure build to jenkins, and then jenkins to source forge). And I recently cleaned out the jenkins workspace so that file is now lost.

It will be available in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

I've just re-run part of the release job and generated the Windows installer (thanks Jody and Luis for the collaboration on getting this going).

Here you go:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.20.4/GeoServer-2.20.4-winsetup.exe/download

By the way, the "bin" and "windows installer" packages use a stripped down version of Jetty that's good for demoes, not so great for production. Even on Windows, we normally stay away from the installer, rather setup Tomcat and deploy they war file, instead.